# VideoView unable to play video using an url

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a video using a url but it's not working. It always give me error on screen as `Can't play this video.`

I'm using below snippet:

```
   val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(it.url)
   binding.videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
   val mediaController = MediaController(activity)
   mediaController.setAnchorView(binding.videoView)
   mediaController.setMediaPlayer(binding.videoView)
   binding.videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
   binding.videoView.setOnPreparedListener { binding.videoView.start() }
```

`Logcat Error:`

```
 E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -1015)
 E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1015)
```

I'm getting the YouTube url mostly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your app request the `INTERNET` permission? Does Logcat give you any useful info?

Comment: Yes INTERNET permission is defined in Android Manifest. And I have updated the logcat error in question.

Comment: Can you share an example URL that gives you the error?

Comment: Issue was fixed but don't remember the exact solution. thanks for your concern @IshitaSinha